# Keybinding to switch to a specific, hardcoded profile in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way I can define a keybinding with which I can specify a specific profile to switch to in VS Code?

I know that there are keybinding that can popup the profile drop-down menu which can let me choose a profile, but I would like a keybinding in which I can fix a specific profile.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading the source code right, at the time of this writing, there's no way to write a keybinding that switches to a specific profile.

The source code is at https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/ad05897293964be52ad97505124830937d096953/src/vs/workbench/contrib/userDataProfile/browser/userDataProfile.ts#L147. Notice how the action's `run` function doesn't take or use any arguments for specifying the profile to switch to.

If you want such a feature, you could [raise a feature-request issue ticket](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&projects=&template=feature_request.md).